# Function with specified arguments

Tags: typescript

Why in the following code am I allowed to assign function with different signature than specified by variable type? How should I change `Func` type to not allow such assignments?

```js
type Func = (a: string, ...rest: any[]) => Promise<any>;
let f: Func = () => Promise.resolve() // why no error although string argument is missing?
```

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what is happening is that Typescript does not force you to type out function arguments you don't need. In your case the body of your method does not use any of the passed arguments even if you would type them out. So you can skip them.

However the following is not allowed:

```
type Func = (a: string, ...rest: any[]) => Promise<any>;
let f: Func = (a: boolean) => Promise.resolve()
```

Because right now the function signatures certainly do not match.

You can however pass a part of the arguments. The following IS allowed:

```
type Func = (a: string, ...rest: any[]) => Promise<any>;
let f: Func = (a: string) => Promise.resolve()
```

Even though we skip the `...rest` argument the function signature is still accepted by Typescript.

Think of it like this: if your function signature has no arguments defined you also cannot do any calculations on arguments passed to the function. Therefore it is not possible to pass arguments of the wrong type. So as far as Typescript is concerned everything is still type-safe :)